# Professor invited me to do research and I agreed, but now I am not so sure

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, interpersonal-issues

I was invited by the professor to work with him. His area is outside of my background and I agreed because I was curious and haven't found a research area yet. After beginning to read papers and learn more, I find I'm less and less interested in the topic. I feel torn as to whether I should continue, and if I shouldn't, how to gracefully exit.

On the one hand, I feel I should develop professional relationships and skills. The topic is a valuable thing to know about. It would be almost wasteful not to take this professor up on their offered mentorship, and rude to stop now. On the other hand, I find other courses much more compelling. I can't really see myself working in this area for PhD work, so it might be a waste of both of our time to continue.

How can I decide whether or not to continue, and if not, how to politely end the relationship without making the professor feel that I've wasted their time?

Comment: Are you currently a PhD student?

Comment: Yes,  I'm a first year PhD student.

Comment: I would say the sooner, the better. Think of it this way, an unwarranted time delay is a waste of everyone's time... Better be open and frank. There is a good chance that your professor has been through a similar experience before. They will understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Before you leave this professor (X), see if there is an other professor (Y) who is working in the field of your interest and he agrees to take you as his advisee.

Also check if there are any restrictions, conditions, permissions,  paperwork from the department to change the advisor.

If all clear, then talk to professor Y about the topic, way of research (theoretical or practical etc.), funding etc. Tell him that you were working with professor X and why you want to leave him.

If all talk is satisfactory and successful, then go to professor X and tell him politely and apologizingly.

I hope things will be fine.